# Convert.FromBase64String(...) throws a FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, iis, base64, iis-express

The following line of code runs fine in **IIS Express**:

```
Convert.FromBase64String("dmVoaWNsZUlkPTE0MTM=??");
```

But when run on my local **IIS 8 server**, it throws the following exception:

> ***System.FormatException:**  The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.*

Why is this happening?

Comment: according to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.71).aspx exception is thrown, when "The length of s, ignoring white space characters, is not an even multiple of 4.".
But why it works on IIS Express... weird

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last two characters "`??`" are not valid in a base 64 string.

Have a read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

The string should end in an alphanumeric character or be padded with one or more `=` characters.

***Edit*** — Decoding the string without the `?` characters returns "`vehicleId=1413`", so I guess it's just a case of removing them.